# Proving the following sequence is bounded (Proof Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I want to prove that the following sequence is bounded,

$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$, $a_1=\sqrt{2}.$

We can prove that it is monotonically increasing by induction. (I'll skip this part and treat it as an assumption.)

Assume $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M\leq a_m < M^2-2$ for $M>2$, the second inequality gives $a_{m+1}<M$ (contradiction because the sequence is increasing.) Then assume $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M^2-2\leq a_m < (M^2-2)^2-2.$ This gives $a_{m+1}<M^2-2$ (also a contradiction.) Repeating the procedure over and over we find that there is no $a_m$ starting from $M$ up to infinity.
Therefore the sequence is bounded.

Is the logic sound? Also is there a better way to write the proof?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry I forgot to add that $a_1=\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: I don't understand the logic here at all. Note it's easy to simply show that $a_n<2$.

Comment: $a_{n+1}>a_n$ if $-2 < a_n<2$. You did not prove $(a_n)$ fits in the interval $(-2,2)$ so you can't assume the sequence is increasing. So you have no starting point for your proof.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The idea is to divide $\mathbb{R}$ into intervals: $(M,M^2-2),(M^2-2,(M^2-2)^2-2)$ and so on. And proving that there doesn't exist any $a_m$ in any of these intervals.

Comment: @CiaPan Can we prove it by induction? $a_2>a_1$ and $a_{n+2}\geq a_{n+1} \implies a_{n+1}\geq a_{n}$. Does that still require that we prove $a_n \in (-1,2)$? Also the interval should be $(-1,2)$, right?

Comment: Yes, you possibly _can_ prove it by induction (with some additional assumptions), but you did not do that.

Comment: Just test: what is the value of $\sqrt{2+a}$ for $a=-1$...? And for $a=-1.9$?

Comment: @CiaPan Yes I skipped proving the monotonic increasing part. This is not my question.

Comment: @MostafaAlkady, Do you understand how my proof proves convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof uses the phrase "Repeating the procedure over and over". This is not a finite proof, thus not valid. Also you seem to use proof by contradiction where I don't see necessary.

Here's my proof which uses induction:

We will show that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded by $2$. It is easy to see that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive reals, so we instead check, by induction, if  $a_n<2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The basis step is easy, since $a_1=\sqrt{2}<2$. Now let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and assume $a_n<2$. Consider $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}<\sqrt{2+2}=\sqrt{4}=2.$$ Thus, the inductive step is proved. By Principle of Mathematical Induction, we have that $a_n<2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, the sequence is bounded.

Comment: Nice! I'm just not sure what is meant by "finite proof". I'm self-learning analysis so I tend to add statements such as this because I'm not used so much to the way proofs are written.

Comment: Proof is a finite sequence of propositions. So your proof statement must be finite. However, "repeating this forever"-type of proof, even though it looks life finite, but if you expand it out it is indeed an infinite sequence of steps. This is not allowed. You need induction to convert your "repeating this" type of argument into a finite deduction.

Comment: Great. Is this type of proofs always not valid? Because this trend of observing patterns carrying out to infinity is almost ubiquitous. Do I always have to resort to induction?

Comment: In the informal situation, the idea suffices. But in the formal situation, one shouldn't attempt this. Nevertheless, I sometimes do not adhere to this advice because at some point writing down a perfect proof become rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis $$(\exists m\in \Bbb N ) : M\le a_m<M^2-2$$

implies a contradiction $(a_{m+1}<a_m)$, hence, this hypothesis is false.

An other way :
The sequence is increasing and if it converges to $ L $, then
$L=\sqrt{L+2} \; or \; L=2 $ and $$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\; a_n<2$$

this can be proven easily by induction :
$$a_{n+1}<\sqrt{2+2}=2$$

Answer (score 1):

All of your numbers ($M$, $M^2-2$, $\left(M^2-2\right)^2-2$, …) are greater than $2$. So, you have not considered all possible cases.

Note that, of $f(x)=\sqrt{2+x}$ and if $0<x<2$, then$$f(x)-x=\sqrt{2+x}-x=\frac{2+x-x^2}{\sqrt{2+x}+x}=\frac{(x+1)(2-x)}{\sqrt{2+x}+x}>0$$and that therefore $f(x)>x$. Also, $f(x)<2$, since$$2-f(x)=2-\sqrt{2+x}=\frac{2-x}{2+\sqrt{2+x}}$$and therefore $2>f(x)$. So, since $a_1=\sqrt2$, $a_1<a_2<2$. Since, $a_2<2$, $a_2<a_3<2$ and so on…

Comment: Since $M>2$, I proved that there can't be any $a_n>2.$ Therefore 2 is an upper bound. I'm not trying to find the least upper bound. So what is wrong with starting the intervals from 2?

Answer (score 1):

Taking nested roots of positive numbers leads one to think that $0$ is a lower bound for $(a_{n})$ so we do the following:

Since $a_{1} > 0$, suppose $a_{n} > 0$ for some $n$.

Then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{(2+a_{n})} > 0$. By induction, $a_{n} > 0$ for all $n$. I assumed a limit existed and saw that it would be $2$ if it did. This made me consider $2$ being an upper bound.

Since $a_{1} < 2$, suppose $a_{n} < 2$ for some $n$.

Then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{(2+a_{n}}) < \sqrt{(2+2})=\sqrt 4 = 2$. By induction, $a_{n} < 2$ for all $n$.

Hence $0<a_{n}<2$ for all $n$ and $(a_{n})$ is bounded.

To prove monotonicity, check $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$, and we see it is the case that $a_{1} \leq a_{2}$.

Suppose for some $n$ that $a_{n} \leq a_{n+1}$.

Then we must show that $a_{n+1} \leq a_{n+2}$.

That is, $a_{n+1} \leq a_{n+2} \Longleftrightarrow\sqrt{2+a_{n}} \leq \sqrt{2+a_{n+1}} \Longleftrightarrow 2+a_{n} \leq 2+ a_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow 
a_{n} \leq a_{n+1}$

Since $(a_{n})$ is bounded and monotonic, the sequence converges.

Comment: I'm trying to prove the convergence of the sequence eventually, therefore I can't assume the limit exists. (Sorry if this was not clear).

Comment: You never claimed in your question that the goal was to prove that there is no $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_n>2$.

Comment: @MostafaAlkady, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @DerekLuna Great but the choice of 2 was obvious because we know the sequence is actually convergent to 2. But in general, how should one go about proving it's bounded?

Comment: We didn't know the sequence converged to 2 until I proved the sequence was monotonic as well. I had my reason for choosing 2 that I wrote up above for you. You can see clearly it grows very slowly since we are nesting into a square root from the start. You could have chosen $10$ and it would have been good enough to bound it.

Comment: You said you want proof verification, then you say you want bound, then you say prove convergence, then you say the bound was obvious since we know it is convergent. Why are you the way that you are?

Comment: We've shown it is increasing so now suppose a limit $L$ exists and since the sequence is represented by a recurrence relation, take $n$ approaches $ \infty $ so that $ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+a_{n}} \implies L = \sqrt{2+L}$ so that $L^{2} = 2+ L$, and by the quadratic formula or by inspection we get that $L = 2$. Using all this information, it makes perfect sense to check for an upper bound of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The logic is flawed, because you start from an unjustified assumption that your sequence is increasing.

It actually is increasing, but in some interval only, and you didn't show what the interval is nor the starting point belongs to the interval.

The interval is $(-2,2)$ and the starting point does belong to it, hence the sequence is increasing and, as a result, it is bounded – but your reasoning does not prove it.